# Is PHP not always a server side technology?

Tags: php

In [the FAQ section of the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.javascript-variable), I came across this:

> Since Javascript is (usually) a client-side technology, and PHP is (usually) a server-side technology...

I understand what they mean about Javascript, but in what other contexts can PHP be used?

Comment: You can actually [create GUIs with PHP](http://gtk.php.net/)

Comment: I use PHP in `cmd` all the time.

Comment: PHP can run anywhere the php interpreter is available. It's **USUALLY** server-side only, because Joe Average will not have php installed on their home computer.

Comment: PHP *could* run in the browser with appropriate plugins or possibly an interpreter for it written in Javascript, though I'm not aware of any such thing and I wouldn't know why you'd want that. However, PHP can perfectly be executed in any non-server computer as well, from the command line for example.

Comment: i use PHP for cli scripts all the time instead of writing bash scripts

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three main areas where PHP scripts are used.

1. **Server-side scripting**. This is the most traditional and main target
   field for PHP. You need three things to make this work. The PHP
   parser (CGI or server module), a web server and a web browser. You
   need to run the web server, with a connected PHP installation. You
   can access the PHP program output with a web browser, viewing the
   PHP page through the server. All these can run on your home machine
   if you are just experimenting with PHP programming. See the
   installation instructions section for more information.
2. **Command line scripting**. You can make a PHP script to run it without
   any server or browser. You only need the PHP parser to use it this
   way. This type of usage is ideal for scripts regularly executed
   using cron (on *nix or Linux) or Task Scheduler (on Windows). These
   scripts can also be used for simple text processing tasks. See the
   section about Command line usage of PHP for more information.
3. **Writing desktop applications**. PHP is probably not the very best
   language to create a desktop application with a graphical user
   interface, but if you know PHP very well, and would like to use some
   advanced PHP features in your client-side applications you can also
   use PHP-GTK to write such programs. You also have the ability to
   write cross-platform applications this way. PHP-GTK is an extension
   to PHP, not available in the main distribution.

Source -http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatcando.php

Answer (score 1):

I've used it before with http://www.bambalam.se/bamcompile/ to create standalone .exe's.

For tossing something quick together without any libraries, and just a single .exe, it's absolutely awesome.  It doesn't support PHP 5 which is kind of a drag, but cool regardless.